# Only first radio button can be selected with inline-block applied to labels

Tags: css, radio-button

Here's a series of three `radio` buttons wrapped in `label` elements. `display: inline-block` is applied to labels. For some reason only the first label can be selected, although on Firebug all labels appear well separated:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgmjrLgy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use 1 ID for each label FOR.
Also you need a group name which must be the same as in the other options.

```
<label for="pa_couleur1">
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="pa_couleur1" value="blanc">blanc
</label>
<label for="pa_couleur2">
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="pa_couleur2" value="bleu">bleu
</label>
<label for="pa_couleur3">
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="pa_couleur3" value="marron">marron
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0jLdst52/5/